# How to scrape an image src using puppeteer in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the source of the first image with a specific class. On the page, there are multiple images with different additional classes but they share the class `opwvks06`. I have tried the following:

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/radiosalue/photos/?ref=page_internal';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 500 });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });

    const image = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const getImage = document
        .querySelector('img[class="opwvks06"]')
        .getAttribute('src');
      return getImage;
    });

    console.log(image);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

However, this returns null. Following is the html structure.
[image]

Comment: If you want the first one, have you tried adding [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) to your query selector? Probably the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, it is still returning null.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans How would you add the first child?

Comment: `document.querySelector('img.opwvks06:first-child')?.src` to select the first image from the set of images with class `opwvks06`. And then we use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that if that element exists, we get its `src` value, and if it doesn't, we do nothing (e.g. the result will be `undefined`).

Comment: Yes, tried exactly this. Returns `undefined`.

Comment: The class attribute is not exactly equal to `opwvks06` which is what `'img[class="opwvks06"]'` tests for. Try `querySelector('img.opwvks06')`

Comment: It's not being able to target that specific image.

Comment: @James Still returning null.

Comment: running `document.querySelector('img.opwvks06:first-child')?.src` on the URL you're making puppeteer load works perfectly fine in a normal browser, so it's time to start looking at what actual page you're getting back from facebook. They don't like getting scraped, so it's entirely possible you're not getting the page content you normally get.

Answer (score 1):

To the answer Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans all you had to do was add:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("img.opwvks06:first-child");
```

You can also try using Stealth Puppeteer if the site is protected from bots, but in your case it is not necessary. Here is the final code:

```js
  (async () => {
    let browser, page;
    let url = "https://www.facebook.com/radiosalue/photos/?ref=page_internal";

    try {
      browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
      page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 500 });
      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 60000 });
      await page.waitForSelector("img.opwvks06:first-child");

      const image = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const getImage = document.querySelector("img.opwvks06:first-child").getAttribute("src");
        return getImage;
      });

      console.log(image);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    } finally {
      if (browser) {
        await browser.close();
        console.log("closing browser");
      }
    }
  })();
```

Output:

```
https://scontent.fiev13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/279856934_10159266106247585_585375152905621309_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p206x206&_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-6&_nc_sid=8024bb&_nc_ohc=owbdAyQwP3wAX-8rdo5&_nc_ht=scontent.fiev13-1.fna&oh=00_AT8yJizEIWx8oEFLUBb90ZIIj-Q4WLmmiWtpd1aRVy-UkA&oe=627C10A5
closing browser
```